# People Picker configuration

Tags: people-picker

I want to configure people picker on SharePoint 2010 for a trusted domain. I have tried all stsadm command with options, it does not work. Does any body have more information about this issue.

Comment: what you tried, could you please post that and also what you want configure?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help and assistance, the users of trusted domain can browse the SharePoint sites, they want to be able to add alert for an item, but the people picker can not find their name on trusted AD, so I have to configure People Picker to be able to browse the trusted domain and find out the address mail of a user. if you need more information, please let me know.
Thank you.
Stéphane